# Log Returns Linear Regression

Tags: regression, logarithm

I have a data sample of daily log returns and I am unsure how I should do a linear regression on that because of the log returns.

Do you think the regression should be like this:

$$y = a + bx$$

or

$$y = a + b\log x$$

But that would be two times log.

---

Edit:

Thank you so much! I actually think that Cagdas Ozgenc and xboard are right.

I have to  examine the impact of certain calendar events on stock returns for a market. And I have a  sample of daily log returns which I have to use.

So the log returns would be $y$ and the events $x$ or ?

Comment: Returns are usually the forecasted variable not the explanatory variable. Are you sure this is what you would like to do?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What is the response $y$ and what is the regressor $X$? Which is the returns? What are you trying to regress / find out?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use those calendar events as features to predict $\log$ returns. In that case, $\log$ returns would be your $y$, and the calendar events would be your $X$.

If you already have the $\log$ returns calculated, simply pass that into your regression function. If you only have the returns, then you would want to take the $\log$ before you pass that variable to the regression function. Either way, the regression is something like:

$$
y\sim X$$$$
y = \log\left(
\text{returns}
\right)$$$$
X = \text{calendar events}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is already log transformed, you should use:

`y = a + b*x`

Good introductions to transformation of daily log returns for finance analysis may be seen [here (R)](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/transform-daily-prices-monthly-log-returns-jonathan-regenstein/) or [here (Python)](https://romanorac.github.io/cryptocurrency/analysis/2017/12/29/cryptocurrency-analysis-with-python-part3.html).